# AWS Elastic Load Balancer Redirecting to HTTP Despite HTTPS Configuration

Tags: python, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fastapi

I'm currently facing an issue with an AWS Elastic Beanstalk setup where both the frontend and backend applications are deployed separately on Elastic Beanstalk. The frontend is built with React, and the backend is a FastAPI application. Both load balancers are configured to handle HTTPS traffic, and I have listener rules in place to redirect HTTP (port 80) to HTTPS (port 443).

However, I'm observing a 307 Temporary Redirect to an HTTP URL when making requests to the backend.

Key details:

1. Load Balancer Configuration: Configured with listener rules for HTTP to HTTPS redirection.
2. SSL/TLS Certificate: Valid and associated with the load balancer.
3. Frontend App: React application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk.
4. Backend App: FastAPI application deployed on a separate Elastic Beanstalk environment.

I've thoroughly reviewed the FastAPI route handlers, middleware, and reverse proxy settings. Despite this, I cannot identify why the 307 redirect to HTTP is happening. The frontend React app initiates requests to the backend, and I suspect there may be interactions between the frontend and the load balancer causing this behavior.

Can someone provide guidance on troubleshooting this issue, considering the involvement of separate Elastic Beanstalk deployments for the frontend and backend? Are there specific logs or configurations that should be checked on both the frontend and backend sides? Or if there is anything that I would have to look at in my FastAPI app that would cause this to 307?

Below is my FastApi code snippet for /auth/token is a snippet:

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)

app.include_router(auth_router, prefix="/auth", tags=["Authentication"])

@router.post("/token", response_model=dict)
async def login(user: User):
    return login_user(user)

def login_user(user: User):
    attributes = user_table.scan(AttributesToGet=["userId", "email", "password_hash"])
    users = attributes['Items']
    user_exists = any(item.get('email') == user.email for item in users)
    if not user_exists:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="User not found")
    selected_user = [item for item in users if (item.get('email') == user.email)][0]
    is_verified = verify_password(user.password.get_secret_value(), selected_user.get('password_hash'))
    if is_verified:
        user = selected_user
        user.pop("password_hash")
        token_data = {"sub": user.get("email")}
        token = encode(token_data, HASH_SECRET, ALGORITHM)
        save_audit_trail(user_id=user.get('userId'), action_type="login", description="Logged In to system")
        return {"access_token": token, "token_type": "bearer", "user": user}
    raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid Login Credentials.")
```

Any insights or assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell if the 307 is coming from the ALB or from the web server?  The logs should tell you.